# How can I attribute an entire paragraph to a source?

Tags: quotations, journalism

I need to summarize an interview for a news article across a few sentences in a single paragraph that uses a series of paraphrased remarks.

Specifically, I'm looking for examples of clean ways to make it clear that the entire paragraph is a summary of what the source said, not the journalists ideas. I'd like to avoid adding phrases to every sentence such as"she said," "they added," or  "according to Joe."

Here's an example full of attributions to show the awkwardness I'm looking to avoid.

> According to Dave Thomas, the Whopper is a great sandwich. It has
> lettuce, tomato, and even mayonnaise, he added. Mr. Thomas said that
> it's flame broiled, which means it's cooked over an open flame. The
> bun is topped with sesame seeds, which add a nice crunch, according to
> Mr. Thomas. He finally finished by explaining how difficult it will be
> to attribute all of these juicy factoids.

Comment: It's not entirely clear what you mean. Please provide more clarity, with some simple examples. So long as you don't provide direct quotations, it's fine to paraphrase along with attribution.

Comment: You have to say something like *X said that [whatever, without quotes]*, *according to X [whatever]*, or *to paraphrase X*, and then say what you want to say, and also provide a citation. But you can paraphrase everything you need in the entire paragraph, borrowing from difference sources within the same source, providing a citation only at the end.

Comment: So are you saying that in my real-life example citing my exclusive interview with the founder of Wendy's, I could write: "According to Dave Thomas, the Whopper is a great sandwich. It has lettuce, tomato, and even mayonnaise. It's flame broiled, which means it's cooked over an open flame. The bun is topped with sesame seeds, which add a nice crunch. He finally finished by explaining how difficult it will be to attribute all of these juicy factoids." You're right, now that I've typed it out, it's quite evident that these are all his ideas. If you want to write an answer I'll accept.

Comment: Yes, exactly. So long what you summarize or paraphrase is accurate, then there's no problem with condensing all of the information into a shorter version without actual quotations. You would also need to use a footnote or endnote at some point that references the specific details (time and place, and so on) of the information.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [If I use a quote followed by a citation, then a small sentence from the cited material, should I include another citation?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/470491/if-i-use-a-quote-followed-by-a-citation-then-a-small-sentence-from-the-cited-ma)

Comment: It turns out that I provided an answer to that other question that asked essentially the same thing. (My answer there would be pretty much the same as any answer I would give here.)

Comment: @JasonBassford It's unclear to me how that answers the question I asked. In my example, I already showed I was aware of the fact that quotation marks and/or direct quotations don't need to be used. 

Also, the suggested duplicate is about academic citations specifically and within a single sentence. The question I asked is about avoiding awkward general attribution across multiple sentences in a paragraph.

Comment: Why the downvotes?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The awkwardly worded example could be re-written as follows, where it's still evident that these are all Dave Thomas's ideas.

> According to Dave Thomas, the Whopper is a great sandwich. It has
> lettuce, tomato, and even mayonnaise. It's flame broiled, which means
> it's cooked over an open flame. The bun is topped with sesame seeds,
> which add a nice crunch. He concluded by explaining how
> difficult it will be to attribute all of these juicy factoids."

Comment: Why the downvote?